# How can I execute osgi command in code

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

I am using Equinox.  I wanna execute osgi command in code.

ex. install bundle command

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

    String cmd = "install file:///e://testBundle.jar"

    // How can I execute cmd in code？
    ...
}
```

thanks for help

Comment: do you want to execute commands to install a bundle, or you are more interested in any command? Installing/Updating a bundle in osgi is easy, and you don't have to rely on a command to do this.

Comment: I know how to install a bundle in osgi, but I wanna dynamic execute start/stop/install/remove command in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage bundles through the BundleContext, or an instance of a Bundle:

1. `BundleContext.installBundle` allow you to install a bundle from an URL
2. You can find a `Bundle` instance with the BundleContext. See for example `BundleContext.getBundles()`. On a `Bundle` instance, you can call `start()`, `stop()`, `update()` or `uninstall()`

See: [BundleContext](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) and [Bundle](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html)

If you really want to access to a shell and execute commands, Equinox uses Apache Felix Gogo Shell. You should get a reference to a `CommandProcessor`, create a `CommandSession` from this processor, and call `execute` on this session.

```
@Reference
CommandProcessor commandProcessor;

...

CommandSession commandSession = commandProcessor.createSession(System.in, System.out, System.err);
commandSession.execute("..");
```

Comment: thank you.  BundleContext.installBundle works.  But CommandProcessor can't import.

Comment: To access `CommandProcessor` and `CommandSession`, add dependency to group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime'.